# Serlvet - loop through array passed by post

Tags: jsp, servlets

I would like to ask for help with this task:
I have a JSP page fragment like this:

```
<form name="Cart" action="Cart" method="post">
 Product no.1 | Count: <input type="text" name="count[1]"><br />
 Product no.2 | Count: <input type="text" name="count[2]"><br />
 <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

I would like to know, how to easy iterate through the array `count` in Servlet - how to get access to concrete counts of concrete products (`count[1]`, `count[2]` etc.)

Thank You.

Comment: It will be available as an array of Strings (`String[]`) using the `request.getParameterValues("count")` method on the server side. Give the elements of your interest a unique name such as `<input type="text" name="count".../>`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try getParameterMap method of HttpServletRequest class:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    Map<String, String[]> parametrs = request.getParameterMap();
    String[] count1 = parametrs.get("count[1]");
}
```

EDIT:
You can also iterate over parameters map values:

```
for (String[] count : parametrs.values()) {
        ...
}
```

Comment: Thank You, but I would like to loop through array count, because I don't know, how many items will be stored in array. Is that possible?

Comment: You can extract key values (count[1], count[2]) from a map: `parametrs.keySet()` and  iterate over them getting the parameter value from a map: `parametrs.get(key)`.